# In using flask with soundcloud library , Why 'no module named moves'?

Tags: python, flask, soundcloud, six

Trying to make use of the [python-soundcloud](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python) package, imported it to implement its server side authentication for my app:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mic import app, db
  File "/Users/harryagbo/Documents/Portfolio/Mojok/mic.py", line 3, in <module>
    import soundcloud
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from soundcloud.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 8, in <module>
    from soundcloud.request import make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .util import get_host, is_connection_dropped
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .response import is_fp_closed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/response.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..packages.six.moves import http_client as httplib
ImportError: No module named moves
```

Comment: Please provide a more coherence [mcve] of your problem please. How exactly are you using this package? Are you writing your own code and this is an error from your own project? Are you simply trying to run the GH link you provided?

Comment: as I know `manage.py runserver` is in Django, not in Flask. Or maybe you mean `Flask-Script` ?

Comment: In just testing the module, I get the same error. Yes you are probably right @furas

Comment: may i ask what you are building i might have alot of useful code for u.

Comment: I am building an application that will play music from soundcloud API's @HollyJohnson

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, not sure how but I'm using Flask==0.10.1 and soundcloud==0.5.0. and none of such issues